# CSS - Newline after dot . of a paragraph

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, line-breaks

I have span which have a paragraph.

```
<span>
Please enter valid Number. Blank Spaces are not allowed to this field. Only Letters, Numbers and Special Characters are allowed.
</span>
```

I need a CSS solution to bring each sentence to new line when it displayed. I tried with \n and br tag. It didn't work because its error message showed by primeFaces validatorMessage and couldn't find anyway to display messages in newline with primefaces solutions as div span cannot be modified. So trying with CSS to make new line after each sentence.

Pls help on this.

[image]

Comment: This won't be possible with CSS alone, as CSS selectors don't allow you to match specific text within a text node like this. If you can't change the HTML for whatever reason, you would have to do it with JavaScript. If you can't add any JavaScript, then I think you may be out of luck here.

Comment: Even with \n or <br>. Its not working. Any way to force to accept those to bring to new line.?

Comment: (Though it is worth noting if you can insert \n into the text then ````white-space: pre-line;```` will do this for you)

Comment: I've added this as an answer for you now, to demonstrate. I didn't realise you meant that you were able to put newlines into the text. If this is the case then this should work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can insert `\n` characters into the text, then `white-space: pre-line;` will break the lines there for you. See example with and without below:

```html
<span>
Please enter valid Number.
Blank Spaces are not allowed to this field.
Only Letters, Numbers and Special Characters are allowed.
</span>
<br /><br />
<span style="white-space: pre-line;">
Please enter valid Number.
Blank Spaces are not allowed to this field.
Only Letters, Numbers and Special Characters are allowed.
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use the `<br>` tag. This tag is used to give a line break.

Comment: Did you try this? Isn't JSF escaping HTML entities on validation messages?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).